# Issues with jQuery slider to load content into the slide being shown

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a slide made with jQuery. It is 936px long. All the separate slide pieces have the class of .slide and unique ids, and are wrapped by a #slideinner div.

My intention was that whenever a div with the class of .slide comes into view it loads content from an outside html page; and whenever the slide would change and the div would not in view (i.e it’s either to the left or right) then it would get rid of the loaded content and would just be an empty div, this would repeat whenever it came in view or was out of it.

To detect weather the .slide div was in view I used the [viewport](https://github.com/NV/jquery_viewport) jQuery plug-in.

However, the way I have coded things does not seem to make them work how I intended them to.

I shall show you what I have done and hopefully you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I load the slide.js(the script which animates my slide) script along with viewport.js and jQuery in head part of the page and then add the following code to each div with the class of .slide.

This is what I used for slide one, and three.

Slide 1

```
<div id="homes" class="slide">
        <script type="text/javascript">
$('#homes').load('pageone.html #homepage');

</script>               
</div>
```

Slide 2

```
<div id="blogs" class="slide">
         <script type="text/javascript">

$('#blogs').ready(function () 
    {

    $('.control').bind('click', function()

    {

if ($('#blogs').is(":in-viewport"))
    {

             $('#blogs').load('pagetwo.html #blog');

    }
else                                
{ 
    $('#blogs').empty();
}               

});             
});
```

Slide 3

```
 <div id="portfolio" class="slide">
          <script type="text/javascript">


  $('#portfolio').ready(function () 
        {     


$('.control').bind('click', function()

        {

  if ($('#portfolio').is(":in-viewport"))

        {

    $('#portfolio').load('pagethree.html #homepage');

        }

  else                      

  {

    $('#portfolio').empty();

  }  
                                                      });       
   });

  </script>             
  </div>
```

I am using four slides all in all.
The last slide follows the same pattern as slide 2 and 3(same code, different ids selected and page loaded.)

The .control is the class name of the left and right arrows which move the slide.

The reason that my first slide does not have the same code as slide two and my other ones is because its content is not loaded when the page is loaded; because it relies on the click event to check whether it is in viewport.

This is a compromise I could live with but the following are the big problems I need to fix.

The issues I have are as follows:

First, when the page is loaded and I click the right arrow, and a new slide comes in, firebug shows that all the slides have loaded the content from their html pages, even though they are not in view.
 Where as only slide 2’s content should be loaded (and slide 1’s because It has no .empty method)

At first I thought that this was an issue with the viewport plug-in or how was using it however then I noticed a second problem.

Second, when I reached the last slide (slide 4 in this case) all the slides still had their content loaded; however when I clicked the left arrow to go back to the third slide all the slides (apart from slide 1 off course) executed the .empty command and were blank.

If I clicked the left arrow one more time, to go to slide 2, the slides would once again load all their content and I would see the content of slide 2.

This has confused me as to whether it is the viewport plug-in issue, or how I used it, or the code I wrote, or perhaps an oversight.

What I want, in essence is, to have each of the .slide divs load content from an outside page if they are the slide being viewed by the user, and remove that loaded content, or stay empty if they are not being viewed by the user.

I hope there is a way to improve this code to do just that, or perhaps a different way to do it. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you give us an example please?